# sql query doesn't work in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, node-mysql

Okay, I got a sql query here, and I want to put a dynamic value in `userID` but when I put this query with another query, It seems like the whole sql query doesn't work. I think It has some problem with template string but no clue why It's not working.

**query that I'm trying to use**

`insert into CREDIT values (uuid(), userID, null, now(), now(), 3.00, 'C', now(), now(), null, null);`

**actual js code**

```
let query = "UPDATE USER SET STATUS = 'C' WHERE CONFIRM_KEY = " + ${mysql.escape(req.params.id)}
   query += `INSERT INTO CREDIT VALUES (uuid(), ${req.params.id}, null, now(), now(), 3.00, 'C', now(), now(), null, null)`

let result = await pool.query(query)
```

**error**

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'INSERT INTO CREDIT VALUES (uuid(), \'66915b91-f9f7-11e7-8ffe-8785394e9837\', null,\' at line 1' }
```

Comment: @thisDonkey like `WHERE CONFIRM_KEY = " + "'" + {mysql.escape(req.params.id)} + "'"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to combine an update and an insert in a single query. That's not possible. Execute each as a separate query.